# Advice: Scraping, SQL and web application run online

Tags: python, sql, scrapy, cloud

(I'm very new to web development.)

I use information that I scrape using **scrapy** and **scrapyd** to parse data into **MySQL**, then a python script converts that data into data that I upload to my website. I would like to automate this process, I just dont know how I should go about it.

- *Do I need  MySQL cloud for this?*
- *Do I need to use something like Heroku to run my python script in the back end?*
- *Do I need something like "python anywhere" to run scripts online and tell scrapyd to run?*

I want this process to be ongoing without doing anything from my local pc (or while it is off).
I'm willing to spend money or learn other coding languages.

Answer (score 1):

So you want two things: a place to store data and some computational power to run crawler itself.
Next you're having two options:

**First one(Geeky)**. Buy sort of VPS(virtual private server) install all the needed infrastructure: mysql, scrapy, daemons and monitoring.

**Second one**: buy some cloud storage(mysql as a service) and use [scrapy in cloud](https://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud). Pair these two services and enjoy (:

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into this right away. Appreciate it!